# Converting a SQL server .bak file in to a DB in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-backup

I have a trouble with SQL Server database backup file which has the .bak extension. What I need to know is, can I use this .bak file in MySQL Workbench and use this as a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can not use that.
If you want to transfer the data from the backup file to MySQL, you must resore the backup to a SQLServer, and then run some data transfer utility to transfer the data from SQLServer to MySQL.

Comment: Ohhh.Can't i even get the structure of the database. I mean like tables? I don't have sql server installed on my computer. can't even run the setup(ending up with a error).

Comment: I am afraid so. MicroSoft does not open its backup file format for SQLServer. So there is no utility or software to open/edit the .backup file directly (As far as I know). If you cannot run the setup, you can try another version, e.g., SQLServer 2008, SQLServer 2010, etc ?

Comment: ahh thanks .and that error, when i just double clicked the setup it says NATIVE SQL INSTALL BOOTSRAPPER HAS STOPPED WORIKING.

Comment: Please make sure the version of SQLServer is correct (X86 or X64) according to you platform. Also some SQLServer requires .Net Framework. You may try installing/upgrading .Net Framework before you install the SQLServer.